# Reinventing the Wheel: the time class

Tags: c++

I am trying to reinvent the wheel and I want to create a time class in c++, I do want this class to be dependent of any c/c++ std libraries, why ? because I am writing a small OS for fun, but I can't seem to find to find information regarding how I would start. can anyone lead me in the right direction ? most of the search I find are just how to use a std library to get time...

Thanks

Sorry let me fix that a small os that is x86 for now.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your environment.  A "small OS" for what system?  Your x86 PC?  Your iPhone?  There is no standard way to get the time in C++ prior to C++0x.

Comment: ... what features do you want in a time class? If you're building your own OS, what system calls will it offer (if any) to get the current time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older PCs have an RTC (Real Time Clock) the never ones use HPET (High Precision Event Timer).

Dig into the linux kernel source if you want to see how to program them. Unices also have a clock associated with the running process which is only ticking when the process is running, this is entirely an OS feature.

Update: http://www.intel.com/hardwaredesign/hpetspec_1.pdf

Comment: This is what I was looking for how to program a real time clock.  a system time clock thanks =D

Comment: would this work cross-platform, sorry I haven't been given good specs he guy was like write a clock for this, it should work cross platform.

Comment: Are you writing a cross-platform OS? omg. it should work with x86

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just look at the time class code? You can easily view any code in the standard library.

Comment: hmmm I assumed it to be in o files not actual c files I will take a look

Comment: It'll most likely be in a header file (ie. time.h) or something.

Comment: You can certainly nick the _interface_ from the .h files. The implementation won't be in there, but nicking that could be a copyright violation. (The _standard_ library is called that because it has a standard interface, not a standard implementation, so you can legally use that interface)

Comment: Yes you're right. Looking at the interface will be a good start, though.